# Find and rename files/folders using regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, rename

I am trying to find a right regex for the filename that starts with I0[0-9][0-9]- eg: "I097-". I am not familiar with regex but using online, I came up with this [I][0][\d][\d][-], I am sure this is not the best regex pattern for the string I have, but I tested using online regex tools and it works. Now I want to use Linux 'find' to find all the files that match this regex and re-name the resulting files by replacing the matching string with nothing.

```
From:
I071-PTEN-7
./I071-PTEN-7/I071-PTEN-7.txt

To:
PTEN-7
./PTEN-7/PTEN-7.txt

command used:
find . -name "I0*" -type f -o -name "I0*" -type d -exec rename -n "s/[I][0][\d][\d][-]/''/" {} \;
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything, not sure what is going on. Any help to find the issue or solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-execdir` option to get only filenames entries in `find` also there is no need to use character class around every character in your regex.

```
find . -name 'I0*' -execdir rename -n 's/^I0\d\d-//' {} \;
```

If `rename` isn't working then you may try this:

```
find . -type f -name 'I0*' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/I0[0-9][0-9]-/}"' - {} \; &&
find . -name 'I0*' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/I0[0-9][0-9]-/}"' - {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @anubhava. I have tried your command but it doesn't seem to rename the files.

Comment: It echoes all the files and folders I need to rename @anubhava

Comment: Thanks for your help @anubhuva, but I am getting mv error: both file names are same.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. But it leads to another problem. It changed the main folder name and it is not able to rename files inside the folder since the folder name change leads to path change of files inside them.

Comment: Only way I can think of is using 2 find command: `find . -type f -name 'I0*' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/I0[0-9][0-9]-/}"' - {} \; && find . -name 'I0*' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/I0[0-9][0-9]-/}"' - {} \;`

Comment: Thanks, it gets the job done though. Appreciate your help.